# Isomorphism between two finite order groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

So, I am self-studying algebra. Thus, I gave myself this exercise: knowing that there is one abelian group of order $5$ (namely $\mathbb{Z}_5$), find an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and this group: 
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\cdot & 0& 1 & 2& 3 &4 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 1 & 4& 0 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
$$
All my efforts have failed. I tried to define a permutation, but this gave me the exact same group. I'm very confused; help is welcome.

Comment: In a cyclic group of prime order every non-identity element is a generator. So pick any element and call it 1, then look at 2 = 1+1, etc.

Comment: The isomorphism from $Z_5$ to your group should send $0,1,2,3,4$ to $0,1,4,3,2$, if it exists.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: That’s not true; if there is one isomorphism, then there are four isomorphisms since you can map the generator to any nontrivial element and get an automorphism. So you could “pre-pend” the isomorphism yhou give with an automorphism of $Z_5$ sending $1$ to $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Oops, true. But if $1 \mapsto 1$, then the rest is determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful advice from the lovely people in the comments, I figured it out. Define the map
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and it follows immediately.